# Как реализовать такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача сверстать вот такой блок (подборка и сравнение приложений):

[image: Подборка и сравнение приложений]

Верстка адаптивная, в зависимости от условий и ширины экрана, кол-во приложений меняется от 5 до 1. Вот как выглядит этот же блок при 320px:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала хотел сделать отдельными блоками, но попыхтев над этим делом часок пришел к выводу, что такой вариант невозможно реализовать главным образом из-за подзаголовков таблицы на всю ширину.

Сейчас думаю сделать таблицами, но тогда получится большая загроможденность html-кода, ведь придется делать дополнительные таблицы (до 4-х штук).

Видите ли вы другие, более рациональные варианты реализации данного блока?

Comment: А табличкой не легче?? Просто делаеш своютаблицу и ставиш дание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень даже легко с медиа-запросами http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWJVzX?editors=1100
**Обновлено**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
   .wrap {
       width: 100%;
   }

   img {
       width: 60px;
       height: 60px;
   }
 .col {
       width: 33%;
       float: left;
   }

   .col > div:first-child {
       text-align: center;
   }

   .col > div {
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }

   .title {
       background-color: #ccc;
       text-align: center;
   }

   .col:first-child .title, .col:last-child .title {
       color: #ccc;
   }


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {


    .col {
       width: 100%;
       float: left;
       margin-bottom: 25px;
   }

      .col:first-child .title, .col:last-child .title {
       color: #000;
   }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text">
            <div>Messenger 1</div>
            <img src="http://www.blogdoandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whats.png">
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="text">
            <div>Messenger 1</div>
            <img src="http://www.blogdoandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whats.png">
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text">
            <div>Messenger 1</div>
            <img src="http://www.blogdoandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whats.png">
        </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="text">text text text text text text text text </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Понятное дело, что без медиа-запросов здесь никак не обойтись.. вопрос не просто в том, как сверстать, а в том, как сверстать так, чтобы эти самые блоки "спрыгивали" вниз при нужном разрешении. Ваш вариант не предусматривает такой возможности, так как вы делали блоки по рядам..

Comment: @Игорь этого я в вопросе не видел, и сразу не подумал, делается аналогично, просто в десктопной fullsize версии скрываете сразу необходимые ячейки, в версиях для таблетки и телефона их по одному открываете.

Comment: Возможно, сформулировал вопрос недостаточно точно, за что прошу меня простить. Постараюсь выразиться как можно точнее, потому что вижу вы меня опять неверно поняли.

В идеале (то, что я пытаюсь тут выяснить), мне нужно сверстать этот блок таким образом, чтобы при ресайзе окна браузера или просмотре с гаджетов разрешением 480px и меньше, эта, так сказать, таблица, преобразовывалась вот в такие блоки:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/FwqXR.png

Сколько их в таблице, столько и блоков должно быть вместо неё.

Comment: @Игорь переделал пример, для десктопной версии + мобильная http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWJVzX?editors=1100

Comment: Чёрт возьми, вроде бы очевидное решение, но я бы до него не додумался) Спасибо за помощь!